# Get the name of an instance of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, typeid

Lets say we have this class

```
class IntArray {

string name;



};
```

and we have this driver

```
 int main(){

 IntArray xe;



 return 0;
 }
```

Basically, how would we store that name of the instance, the "xe" through the constructor and into the data member "string name"?

Comment: For what would you need that? Symbols usually aren't accessible at runtime.

Comment: C++ doesn't natively provide RTTI. There are some libraries that make this available, but not exactly in the way that you are asking.

Comment: You could create a macro to encapsulate this pretty easily, but the syntax escapes me at the moment. Something like `#define CreateIntArray(name) (IntArray name(name))`, using the constructor in @Swordfish's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get C++ object name in run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468956/get-c-object-name-in-run-time)

Answer (score 6):

C++ does not support doing this. Variable names are only something you as a developer are aware of. The compiled program doesn't have them. Your `std::string name` field inside the `class IntArray` would not hold "xe"; it would just be uninitialized.

You could, however, use a map - an `std::unordered_map<std::string, IntArray> arrays` to be exact -  and then use `arrays["xe"]` to access the array you like using a runtime-defined string. See [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) on CPPReference for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>

class IntArray
{
    std::string name;
public:
    IntArray(std::string name) : name{ std::move(name) } {}
};

int main()
{
    IntArray xe{ "xe" };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have some trick to solve your problem.  Instead of using directly the constructor, just use a macro, like:

```
#define DECL(x) x(#x)
```

in some common header you `#include` in your application.  Instead of declaring

```
IntArray ex;
```

do

```
IntArray DECL(ex);
```

on expansion, you will get something like:

```
IntArray xe("xe");
```

you can also use the variadic macro expansion of latest standards to be able to call a different constructor.

```
#define DECL(name, ...) name(#name, #__VA_ARGS__)
```

If you want, you can also include the type in the macro, so:

```
#define DECL(type, name) type name(#type, #name)
```

and declare your variable with:

```
DECL(IntArray, ex);
```

That will expand to:

```
IntArray ex("IntArray", "ex");
```

this trick is far from complete, but can help you to avoid mistakes because of mispelling variable names as a consequence of having to write twice in source code.

Comment: You're missing the `#` on `name` in your 5th source snippet. If I'm not mistaken, it should read: `#define DECL(name, ...) name( #name, #__VA_ARGS__)`.