# Initialize member string with class object name in C++?

Tags: c++, variable-names, class-members

Is there a way to instantiate an object and have a string member take the object's name? I would also not mind for a gcc builtin.

Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
    
class A
{
    std::string obj_name_ = /* set to the objects name (very_descriptive_name) somehow */ ;
};
    
A very_descriptive_name; // naming the *object* should be enough, do we really have to initialize the string with exactly the same name?
```

The string is later used for recognisability.

Comment: the name of a variable != name of an object. Consider that you can do `A& a_completely_different_name = very_descriptive_name;`, now the two refer to the same object via completely different names. You can do `A a("very descriptive name");`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your point. Couldn't you add a member function returning to string `very_descriptive_name.str()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/469108/7157435 This might help you

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: I know you can do that but that's an extra step. I want the member string to be *infered* from from the object name

Comment: @Bob_: I don't think you understand the point. I wanted to create an object which takes its object expression name and initializes a string member with it.

Comment: @ShivCK: Thanks I think the macro solution could work, however its a bit hacky. I thought there might be other more elegant solutions.

Comment: @glades macro is the only solution in C++

Comment: Objects don't need to be named variables. What would the name be if the object is a temporary or unnamed function parameter? There is no standard way of doing this and I doubt that there will be a gcc-specific solution in general.